# shadowsocks client runs but no effect

Tags: settings, shadowsocks

It looks like everyone is using a Linux VPS as server and Windows machine as client, which I was able to make it work too.

However, I need to get it work the other way around: Shadowsocks server on windows (where I am authorized to access outside servers), and client on my Linux machine (where I need to get tools for my data analysis work).

Here are configuration I use:

```
# windows ssserver config json
ssconfig.json
{
  "server":"winID.company.com",
  "server_port":8388,
  "local_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "local_port":1080,
  "password":"notapassword",
  "timeout":300,
  "method":"aes-256-cfb",
  "fast_open": false
}
```

and run it on windows cmd:

```
ssserver -c ssconfig.json
```

Configure file on Linux:

```
# CentOS sslocal config json
{
   "server":"winID.company.com",
   "server_port":8388,
   "local_address": "127.0.0.1",
   "local_port":1080,
   "password":"notapassword",
   "timeout":600,
   "method":"aes-256-cfb"
}
```

run sslocal in terminal:

```
sudo sslocal -c ~/bin/ss-win.json -d start
```

Both run withnot error message. But it doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Back story:

Why I want to do this? Here is the issue when I started in a hospital a few months ago:

- Everything runs on Windows 7
- IT knows nothing about Linux, and does not want do anything about it.
- github and like are blocked, unless you get approval for accessing "freeware" websites.

I have been approved for access github.com, centos.org etc. but it ties to my log in, and IT has no clue or desire to add my linux machine to the windows active directory and use my login for linux.

I am getting a new machine that is powerful enough. I am thinking to have a windows VM and a centos VM on top of ESXi, and CentOS will use windows VM (where I login and have access to outside world) as 'proxy'.

Should it work?